# Spring AOP LTW doesn't work, weaving doesn't happening

Tags: java, spring, aop, xml-configuration, load-time-weaving

I'm creating simple experimental program, which use LTW to weave aspect into a class, however aspect load-time weaving doesn't happening. You can check and use code, which I will describe later, in [GitHub](https://github.com/SergejsJevstignejevs/spring-aop-ltw). I'm using Java 17 and IntelliJ IDE.

Used aspect:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MonitoringAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.sj.utilities.Watch.*(..))")
    public void monitoringOperation(){}

    @Around("monitoringOperation()")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before " + pjp.getSignature() + " execution!");

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long executingTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Method's execution time:\n"
                + "\t" + executingTime + " ns\n"
                + "\t" + (executingTime / 1000) + " μs\n"
                + "\t" + (executingTime / 1000000) + " ms\n"
                + "\t" + (executingTime / 1000000000) + " s");
        System.out.println("After " + pjp.getSignature() + " execution!");

        return retVal;
    }

}
```

I tried to remove @Component, because aspect bean is not required, however it changed nothing.

Advised by aspect is simple method *sleeping* of *Watch* class, with implementation of FictiveWatch interface (Interface exists only for Spring to use JDK dynamic proxies).

Created Java annotation config:

```java
@Configuration
//@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@ComponentScan("com.sj")
public class AOPConfig implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public LoadTimeWeaver getLoadTimeWeaver() {
        return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    }

    @Bean
    public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver()  throws Throwable {
        return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    }

}
```

As well as xml config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans <!-- namespaces ...-->

    <!-- this switches on the load-time weaving -->
    <context:load-time-weaver
        weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>

    <!-- this switches on the spring aop autoproxy -->
    <!--<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>-->

    <!-- a service object; we will be profiling its methods -->
    <bean id="watch"
          class="com.sj.utilities.Watch"/>
    <bean id="monitoringAspect"
          class="com.sj.aspects.MonitoringAspect"/>

</beans>
```

To use weave aspect I use this META-INF/aop.xml file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver
            options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.sj..*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.sj.aspects.MonitoringAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Driver class:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Check used JVM arguments
        System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments());

        //Java class LTW config
        //ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AOPConfig.class);

        //XML LTW config
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/aop-xml-conf.xml");
        Watch watch = context.getBean(Watch.class);
        watch.sleeping(3000);
    }
}
```

In the driver class, I use AnnotationConfig or XMLConfig to use LTW, but weaving isn't happening, so crosscutting functionality isn't applied. As well as I print used by JVM arguments.

The only thing I see, when using AnnotationConfig or XMLConfig, is JVM arguments that I use:

```
[--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dspring.aop.proxy-target-class=false, -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=trace, -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.verbose=true, -javaagent:E:\intelliJIdea_dir\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=55606:E:\intelliJIdea_dir\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.1\bin, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
```

As well as result of *Watch* class *sleeping* method:

```
Slept 3000 ms
```

Why weaving is not happening, which part of written code is not right? As per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.3/reference/html/core.html#aop-aj-ltw) on LTW, as well as   other answers on questions for LTW topic everything should be alright, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you forget to add `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar` or similar?

Comment: Nothing changes if I add it. As well as isn't it already used through IntelliJ -javaagent? (Well, aspectjweaver is specified in -classpath, but IntelliJ idea_rt.jar in -javaagent)

Comment: The IntelliJ javaagent is completely unrelated to AspectJ, you really do need the AspectJ weaver on the JVM command line as a Java agent, not just on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally add the `-javaagent` option to the program arguments instead of VM arguments? For me, your project works nicely.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA: select VM options]

[image: IntelliJ IDEA: show added VM options]

Running the program yields:

```
[AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.19 built on Wednesday Dec 21, 2022 at 06:57:22 PST
[AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa] info register classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa
[AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa] info using configuration .../target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa] info register aspect com.sj.aspects.MonitoringAspect
[--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, -javaagent:src/main/resources/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar, -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56248:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3\bin, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
...
[AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.sj.utilities.Watch.sleeping(long))' in Type 'com.sj.utilities.Watch' (Watch.java:9) advised by around advice from 'com.sj.aspects.MonitoringAspect' (MonitoringAspect.java)
Before void com.sj.utilities.Watch.sleeping(long) execution!
Slept 3000 ms
Method's execution time:
    3010467900 ns
    3010467 μs
    3010 ms
    3 s
After void com.sj.utilities.Watch.sleeping(long) execution!
```

Comment: Well, no, I added it to JVM arguments. But in the end the culprit is this JVM argument: ```-Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=trace ```. It prevented crosscutting functionality from working.

Comment: OMG, why would you use an exotic setting and not even mention it? Can you not start simple instead of complicated? I feel like I wasted a lot of time, cloning your project, trying to reproduce your problem, writing here and making extra screenshots for you.  Please learn how to ask questions.